# Check, Select and Change specific parts of a Date in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date

So I have a list of dates that I am trying to search through and check if they need to be corrected or not. The yellow highlighted cells are examples of changes needed to be made. Wether the date needs fixing or not I want the result of the code to place it in the "Date Fixed" column as shown in the first cell. If the date is not listed as the 30/31st of a month or the 1st then I need to change the day part of the date to either the beginning or end of the month. I have written what I thought would work but I keep receiving a Run Time Error 11 code. Any ideas on how to fix this and keep going through all the dates?

```
Private Sub FormatDate_Click()
Dim myrow As Integer
Dim startrow As Integer
Dim Dates As Date
Dim Datesfixed As Date
Dim dateTwo As Date
Dim dateEnd As Date

myrow = 2
startrow = 2
Dates = Cells(myrow, 2)
Datesfixed = Cells(myrow, 3)
dateTwo = mm / 1 / yyyy
dateEnd = mm / 31 / yyyy

Do Until Cells(myrow, 1) = ""
    If Dates = dateTwo Or dateEnd Then
        Datesfixed = Dates
    ElseIf Dates <> dateTwo Or dateEnd Then
        Dates = dateTwo
    myrow = myrow + 1

    End If
    myrow = myrow + 1
    
Loop
 
myrow = 2
startrow = 2
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do with `dateTwo = mm / 1 / yyyy`? And `dateEnd = mm / 31 / yyyy`?

Comment: "I need to change the day part of the date to either the beginning or end of the month" - it doesn't matter which you change it to?

Comment: It does matter which change happens. If it is in the front half of the month I need it to be the first of the month and if it is the back half of the month I need it to be the end of the month

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```vb
Private Sub FormatDate_Click()
    
    Dim c As Range, dt, d As Long, m As Long, y As Long, dLast As Long
    
    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("B2") 'first date
    
    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0
        dt = c.Value
        d = Day(dt)   'extract the parts of the date
        m = Month(dt)
        y = Year(dt)
        dLast = Day(DateAdd("m", 1, DateSerial(y, m, 1)) - 1) 'last day of the month
        
        If d <> 1 And d <> dLast Then
            c.Offset(0, 1) = DateSerial(y, m, dLast)  'set to last day of the month
        End If
        
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0) 'next date
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: That code works great Tim! The only thing I am having trouble with is that it takes the months (that have 31 days) and changes the date to 30. Is there a way to adjust the code so it takes the 31 dated dates and just copies them over?

Comment: Fixed my "last day of the month" calculation...